# A better way to table cell editing by using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am asking these questions to share and have better understanding about how to implement certain things with Angular better.

**Note* Front-end is Angular. Back-end is Django**

**1.    Inline editing**

On cell click the data becomes editable and it is bound to that cell’s `ng-model`. So when I `ng-blur` from a cell, I send an update to database. Also, I have the position of that cell, so if I need to do anything to that cell in the future, it is just constant time access to my `$scope.array`.  Now there is a small issue here and I am not sure if there is one solid and right solution to this.

- Since editing changes the scope right away, then I am not sure what
  to do in callback functions. The logical thing is to update if
  callback is success and otherwise if error.

  At the moment I implement this way: If success do not do anything,
  otherwise have Django send me the unchanged data to update my record
  (revert the update).

**2.    Using form to edit cells in the row**

I have an extra column for actions (edit, delete …). If a user clicks on edit action, I will load that row’s data into a form. User will make changes and save the new row to database.

- On callback success I get the new updated row. Since I know the
  `$index` of the row in the table, I can still use constant time access
  to `$scope.array` to update that row. On error do nothing (show an
  error or warning message).

> My concern is about being consistent throughout the application. As you noticed, I am using indices a lot to avoid loops. 
>   **Any tips or suggestions on above points?**
>
> **Other issue:** I introduced table sorting which uses `orderBy:’column-heading’:Boolean`. Sorting is happening on the view but that does not reflect on $scope.array. This messes up my indices because they represent positions on the view and not in the `$scope.array`. At this point I am not able to update my `$scope.array` in constant time. I have to use loop. 
>   **Any tips on this issue?**

**Note**: The sorting is done in html `ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:predicate:reverse"`. This does not sort  the actual array and that was messing up my indices. Now I am trying to sort manually. Every time I click on header, `ng-click` will call a function in the controller to use the `$filter` service.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: perhaps I don't fully understand the complexity of the situation in question)

Suppose this is your data that you originally retrieved from the server (I'm assuming that every row is an array of cells since you said that you could sort it by columns):

```
$scope.items = [
  {id: 123, data: [{c: "Col1", v: "aaa"}, {c: "Col2", v: "bbb"}, ..], // row 0
  {id: 456, data: [{c: "Col1", v: "zzz"}, {c: "Col2", v: "www"}, ..], // row 1
  // etc...
];
```

When you render it in the View, each `ng-model` it is properly bound to the right object, whether you sort it or not.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in items">
   <td><button ng-click="edit(row)">edit</button></td>
   <td ng-repeat="cell in row.data | orderBy: '-c'">
      <input ng-model="cell.v" ng-blur="saveItem(row, cell)">
   </td>
</tr>
```

when `saveItem` is called, the actual objects are passed to the function.

```
$scope.saveItem = function(row, cell){
   $log.log(cell);
   YourSvc.saveRecord(row);
}
```

Now, sometimes it's a good idea to keep both master and copy versions of the data. This allows you to reset the view, for example, if HTTP call to the server fails. This is also why I don't think it is a good idea to rely on your backend to send you the "unchanged data" - the HTTP call itself may fail. If that happens, you could choose to reset the data back on the client.

To keep references between master and copy requires a bit more coordination when the data is first cloned, and depends on your data, the granularity of a change, etc.

For example, rows are most granular save units:

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(row){
  row._copy = angular.copy(row.data);
});
```

Then, when you save:

```
YourSvc.saveRecord(row)
   .then(function(data){
      if (data.isSuccess) {
        row._copy = angular.copy(row.data);
      } else {
        row.data = angular.copy(row._copy);
      }
   })
   .catch(function(e){
      row.data = angular.copy(row._copy);
   });
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but `orderBy` does not sort `$scope.items`. If it did I would not have problems with indices.

Comment: What does it sort then? It was my understanding that it sorted cells by columns

Comment: when you use the filter in html, Angular restructures DOM elements only. Not the actual $scope.array. For that I need to use $filter() service to sort the actual array. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: At least that is what messing my indices up. The filter in HTML does not apply changes to the scope array it seems. But on click if I explicitly call a function in my controller that does the sorting by using $filter service, then it does (have not fully tested it yet).

Comment: @Brian, yes - that's all true. Which one are you using and what is the problem?

Comment: i was using the HTML one. So i have to use the other one instead. But my main question was not about wrong indices. I needed some insight on how usually the updates to tables are done in Angular.

Comment: That is what I assumed - and the answer was about sidestepping indices altogether, since you deal with objects directly